# Why `type a = {} extends {a?:number}? true:false;` is true

Tags: typescript

Why `type a = {} extends {a?:number}? true:false;` is true,
but `type b = {a?:number} extends {}? true:false;` is true too!
I think the `{}` is a super type and it can't extends any types, but if
here is a type which all properties of are optional(`?`), `{}` will extends this type, why ?
The core problem is how to judge compatibility betweens types.Before meeting this problem, i always use Set theory to explain them, but it's ineffective for this problem, so i need a new theory, unless typescript did something special to `{}`

Comment: Interesting observation, this means that `type Equals<S, T> = [S, T] extends [T, S] ? true : false` is not transitive, because `Equals<{a?: number}, {}>` and `Equals<{}, {a?: string}>` are both true, but `Equals<{a?: number}, {a?: string}>` is false.

Comment: See [ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479) and linked issues.  It's intentionally unsound to support things like `interface Foo {a?: number, b: string}; const bar = {b: "hello"}; const foo: Foo = bar;`.  Otherwise you'd have a very hard time using optional properties because the compiler generally does not track the absence of properties.

Comment: @jcalz It makes Sense if `?` is bidirectional covariation! Thanks for your example in [ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479)

Answer (score 1):

You could interpret `extends` as 'can be assigned to'. Therefore, `{}` extends any type where all properties are optional.

```
const a: { a?: string, b?: number } = {}; // legal, no error
```

Comment: I think this doesn't quite explain it, because the type `{}` includes values like `{a: 'foo'}` which are not assignable to `{a?: number}`. So the *value* `{}` is certainly assignable to `{a?: number}` but the *type* `{}` is not necessarily.

Comment: Good point, I created this playground to check it:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGB+AXFAdgVwFsAjCAJygF8AoUSKAUQLFAWWqoGMB7HAZ2ChFUpbI2YhWKVNgDkAMy5cZlANyce-QagBe2OIiGkVQA
This is strange, because the type analysis doesn't show an error, yet the `a` property is mistyped. Anyway, this shows how the `{}` type, too, can be assigned to a type with optional properties.

Comment: this example only explains the reason of `type b = {a?:number} extends {}? true:false;  // true`, because   it's from  `{}` to `{ a?: string, b?: number }`，which is a covariant.

Comment: i think `extends` means "can be assigned to" too, but the core problem is how to judge compatibility betweens types.Before meeting this problem, i always use set theory to explain them, but it's ineffective for this problem, so i need a new theory, unless  typescript did something special to `{}`

Comment: @kaya3 This pretty much *does* explain it, it's just that TypeScript's type system is not fully sound, and this is one of the holes.  TypeScript doesn't track absence of properties; there are no exact/sealed/closed object types.  If I write `const foo = {x: 1}`, the compiler infers type `{x: number}` for `foo`, which doesn't actually say anything about properties that aren't `x`.  Both `{x: 1, y: ""}` and `{x: 1, y: false}` are assignable to `{x: number}`. People want to be able to assign `foo` to a variable of type `{x: number, y?: string}`, even though this is unsound.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's the correct answer although it would be nice if it explicitly addressed the unsoundness, and possibly linked to source info like (maybe) [ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479).  TypeScript allows narrowing from `{}` to `{ a?: string, b?: number }` because it's convenient, but if you try to analyze that with set theory / type theory you'll be unhappy because it's not type safe.